# Chain rule for KL divergence, conditional measures

Tags: information-theory, kullback-leibler, mixture-distribution, measure-theory

The chain rule for KL divergence is widely seen in the theoretical machine learning literature and generally referenced to [1, Theorem 2.5.3]:

$$ \text{KL}[p(x, y) \mid q(x, y)]= \text{KL}[p(x) \mid q(x)] + \text{KL}[p(y \mid x) \mid q(y \mid x)] $$

However, the proof here only appears to apply to the case of densities w.r.t. some finite set. Based on quoted results, I assume this holds more generally but have been unable to find a proof of this in under the more general (Radon-Nokodym) definition of KL divergence for probability measures on X:

$$ \text{KL}[p \mid q] = \int_{X} \log\left(\frac{dp}{dq}\right) \ dp. $$

I am looking for a (reference to a) proof and the general conditions under which is possible, ideally without too much heavy measure-theoretic apparatus. My potential applications relate to hierarchical or mixture models so any intuition on that front would also be greatly appreciated.

[1] Elements of Information Theory, Cover & Thomas.

Clarification:

Here $p(x)$ is the marginal distribution of $p(x, y)$ on $x$ and analogously for $q$, as in [1], so $p$ and $q$ are measures on some product space $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$. $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ (in this slight abuse of notation) are the marginals on $\mathcal{X}$.

Part of my question is then what further requirements there are on $p$, $q$, $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ for the above decomposition.

Comment: One first step could be to disambiguate the usages of $p$ and $q$. On the left hand side of the top equation, $p$ and $q$ are applied to two arguments, and on the first term on the right, they are applied to one argument. While this is common abuse of notation in ML literature, what does it mean here?

Comment: This might be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804682/conditional-radon-nikodym-and-disintegration.